# Not able to open pdf in new activity

Tags: android, pdf, render

I'm using [this github](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library) source for my project. I've a listview with 10 elements and 10 different PDFs in `assets` folder. In 1 activity, I'm using `listview` and `onItemClickListener` as shown below:

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_policy_list, mobileArray);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.policy_list);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(PolicyActivity.this, PdfViewerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, getAssets() + "/dummy.pdf");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Code for `PdfViewerActivity` class is as given below:

```
package com.dell.eventapp.ui.activity;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.dell.eventapp.R;

public class PdfViewerActivity extends net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_viewer);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPreviousPageImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.left_arrow;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNextPageImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.right_arrow;
    }

    @Override
    public int getZoomInImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.zoom_in;
    }

    @Override
    public int getZoomOutImageResource() {
        return R.drawable.zoom_out;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPdfPageNumberResource() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPdfPasswordEditField() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When I click on any item in list view, new activity should open up and PDF should be viewed in new activity. When I run my code, I always get this error:

```
02-23 18:19:48.033 8982-8982/com.dell.eventapp I/PDFVIEWER: ST='file 'android.content.res.AssetManager@817d40c/dummy.pdf' not found'
```

I came across this [this issue](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library/issues/26) in github repo's issues. It says that PDF cannot be loaded from Assets folder. You should copy it on sdcard before opening it. How can I work around it?

Comment: Work around [Android - Copy assets to internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218775/android-copy-assets-to-internal-storage)

Comment: Or try out this library
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3761

Comment: I need to pass pdf as extra to new activity, can that `barteksc` can do it?

Comment: Why pass pdf , just pass locations of pdf to next activity

Comment: Okay, let me try that...

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, getAssets() + "/dummy.pdf");
```

`getAssets()` returns an `AssetManager`. `getAssets() + "/dummy.pdf"` calls `toString()` on the `AssetManager` instance, and then appends `/dummy.pdf` to it. This is why you wind up with `android.content.res.AssetManager@817d40c/dummy.pdf`. `toString()` on `AssetManager` does not somehow magically give you a filesystem path to an asset... in part because assets are not files on the device.

> How can I work around it?

Either:

- Follow the instructions in that issue and copy the asset to a file, or
- Modify that library to support an asset, or
- Do not use that library, but use something else that does support displaying a PDF from an asset

FWIW, I have sample apps demonstrating the use of [`pdf.js`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/PDF/PdfJS) and [pdfium](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/PDF/Pdfium) for displaying PDFs from assets.